# How do I send Asian charset plaintext emails in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, unicode

I have an ASP.NET application that needs to send emails in Korean. These emails are sent in plaintext.

But when the emails are received, they look like this:

> ? First name? ??: ?????.
>
> ?? ???? ???? ?? ??? ??? ?? ???? ????
>   ?????  ???? ????. ??????? ??? ?????
>   ???? ??? ??1-888-123-4567 ? ??????? ??
>   info@example.com ?? ??????
>   ???? ??? ??????.

Currently I'm not setting the encoding. Just using the default. Ideally, I would like the encoding to work with all sorts of emails. Hopefully I don't have to set the encoding on a per-email basis.

Comment: What character encoding are you using to send those emails?

Comment: Currently I'm not setting the encoding. Just using the default.

Comment: Did you try encoding the text in UTF-8? I also had a lots of troubles with spanish characters. The <a href="http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html">article about encoding types by Joel Spolsky</a> helped me a lot understanding what to do.

Comment: Sorry for the bad URL. The correct one is: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have 2 ways to encode email parts:

1. Using the Korean Code page for your email so people not using Unicode can still view it (charsets like `ISO-2022-KR` and `x-windows-949`, I don't know which of the 3 is the most common):

   ```
   Content-Type: text/plain;
   charset="EUC-KR"
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
   ```
2. Using UTF8 encoding, which is the preferred way nowadays.
   In any case, the recipient must have proper support for [Asian languages installed on their machine](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/handson/user/xpintlsupp.mspx) for the message to display correctly.

   ```
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
   ```

Here are a couple of good articles that explain how to implement this properly:

- [System.Web.Mail FAQ](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/3.1.aspx)
- [MIME Overview Part I: A brief overview of the MIME specification](http://www.aspnetmime.com/help/welcome/overviewmimei.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the encoding of the email to UTF-8.

I think this would be the line you need in the email headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

Hope this helps

Adam